# swf plays locally but not from Ubuntu web server

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, ubuntu

I have an issue with swf file on ubuntu web server. I built my whole site locally and everything was fine. When I upload my site on my Ubuntu server and tried to see my site from my local browser, the swf file not loaded properly. It just shows the main image and is like AS3 don't runs.

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Usually this sort of problem relates to the cross domain policy file. Try doing a [crossdomain.xml] search here

Comment: does your swf containing any server path or its just a simple swf?

Answer (score 0):

If you work with windows locally, you should check if the filename in your HTML has the same lowercase/uppercase characters as the one of your file. For Windows "test.swf" and "TEST.SWF" are the same file where in linux they aren't.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I solved my problem installing Gnash on my server!

Comment: That fix is not really making sense to me. Gnash is a flash plugin replacement that would be used if you run the flash files locally on that server. If you let the webserver serve the flash files to your local browser, Gnash won't be used at all, so shouldn't change anything.